# What scenario would i use a proxy? Javascript

Tags: javascript

So i've just found out about Proxy's and I've read a bit on the mozilla website. They seem really interesting, but i'm curious as to what situation these are useful?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? [_"Proxy"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy) is a vague term that could refer to any number of software or even hardware components (and that's just in a general computing context)

Comment: These: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: You can also see lots of answers suggesting the use of proxies here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20%22use%20a%20proxy%22%20is%3aanswer%20score%3a3 (some false positives)